# Intuitive understanding of Local Probability Distribution

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I'm learning Bayesian network. I have problem in intuitive understanding of Local Probability Distribution.

Can anybody explain to me what it is?

Comment: I don't know what a Local Probability Distribution is, and a Google search shows up only a paper by an H. Rabbani (couldn't find a definition within). I am not an expert but in case this is not well-known terminology, would you post a definition please? We can help you unravel it.

Comment: I believe you are looking for (local) conditional probability distributions